# Stop redirect & show the dialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to show dialog message to confirm the redirect, but I have my own Dialog window, so that code (look below) isn't ok for me.

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit(e) {
    return "Do you realy want to leave the page, miserable user?";
}
```

If I use, my menu is shown but page redirect before I choose any variant(yes/no):

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit(e) {
    return pcDialog.Show();
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible and is a known security restriction.